# How to force number format on apex:inputText

Tags: visualforce, multi-currency, inputtext, conversion

### Background

We have an org that has **advanced multi-currency** activated. Since this feature is activated we are not enabled to use `apex:inputField` on currency fields. Instead of this we are using `apex:inputText`

> If advanced currency management is enabled, you can't bind Visualforce
>   pages that use `<apex:inputField>` or `<apex:outputField>` components to
>   currency fields that support advanced currency management.

The change of `apex:inputField` by `apex:inputText` to edit currency field works fine.

In addition, We also have **multi-locale** users.

### Problem

When the field is been showing for editing the decimal symbol showed is a dot (When the locale symbol for that should be comma).

[image]

But, when the user try to edit this field and insert a number using comma as decimal separator a conversion error occurs.

[image]

### Failed attempts so far

We've tried to replace using javascript the comma by dot `onsubmit`. But this symbols should depends of user's locale.

Later, we've tried by using `apex:input type=number` but is not possible to join the field to that component.

Also, we have tried to replace the `save` method on the controller, and convert there the text to number, but the same error was showed.

### Query

Is there any standard solution to manage currency fields using an `inputText`?
Can I force the format of `inputText` ?

Thx for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc may be contradictory as I use `apex:inputField` with ACM all day, every day. From the VF standard component reference:

> You can't associate this inputField with a formula merge field of type currency if your organization is using dated exchange rates.

This is saying you can't do this:
`value="{!IF(foo__c,opportunity.amount,opportunity.next_best_amount__c)}"`

but you can certainly do `<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>` as my VF pages do that (actually they do : `<apex:inputField value="{!ow.o.amount}"/>` referring to a wrapper class around Opportunity but that shouldn't matter.

Now outputFields are a different story and here the VF doc is consistent with your ACM doc snippet:

> You cannot associate this output field with a currency merge field if that field value is calculated using dated exchange rates.

I would go with a component and its own controller that could deal with the locale issues. Pass in the currency field to the component and let the component's controller format it for you.

Comment: You are right. I fell into the wrong doc trap. The outputField works fine using a outputText

Answer (score 0):

In the save method in the controller you could replace the comma with a decimal.

```
price.replace(',','.');
```

In the get method you could do the reverse to put the comma in for display.

Instead of:

```
String price{get;set;}
```

Define the get method and replace the decimal

```
public String getPrice(){
    return price.replace('.',',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure Whether @Stephen's answer will work for muli-local.
Check the following link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you Rob, but the browser locale is not always the Salesforce user local and that will give me an issue